# Duplicate adjacency-list

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child, adjacency-list

I have a table for category. Table is typical hierarcal data. Table name is category. 
How to duplicate hierarchical data insert them at the same table, generating new parents and parent-child relationship.

Table stracture

```
id | parent | catname 
1    0        A       
2    1        B       
3    1        F      
4    2        C
5    3        D
6    5        E
```

And like this image.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could u please give a practical example to better understand your problem?

Comment: You say you want to duplicate data, but for me it seems like you're moving data (D and E-child from F parent TO B Parent). Your drawing just made me confused.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Image is updated.

Comment: on what logic you want to duplicate? maybe you can run Scripting loop and than find all child of given Category, and insert them for new category.

Comment: You're using the "adjacency-list" model of representing hierarchical data, which requires recursion to manipulate or access arbitrary levels. Unfortunately, MySQL (unlike some other RDBMS) does not support recursive functions, so it is not well-suited to this model. You might consider restructuring your database to use the "nested sets" or "transitive closure table" models instead. [@Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860) introduces them nicely in his presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: @eggyal Is there any solutions for my request?

Comment: Your images don't match table. ie B,s parent is A== 1, C,s parent is B== 2 etc

Comment: @davidstrachan Now matched... :)

Comment: "*Is there any solutions for my request?*"  Yes: you might consider restructuring your database to use the "nested sets" or "transitive closure table" models instead.

Comment: Why would D have both B & F as parents?

Comment: @eggyal I can not set database model. I'm sorry.